# press a button without id or name with javascript

Tags: javascript, button

i need to press a button in one page, but the button dont have id, name or anything else

only this is the code of the button:

```
<input type="submit" value="continue">
```

there is a way to press it?

i tried this code from here:

```
 function clickButton(val)
{
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) 
  {
     if(buttons[i].type == 'button' && buttons[i].value == val) 
     {
          buttons[i].click();
          break; //this will exit for loop, but if you want to click every button with the value button then comment this line
     }
  }
```

}

but dont worked too, nothing happen, the page refresh but still in the same place

Comment: `document.querySelector('input[type="submit"][value="continue"]').click();` - will work only if used after DOM is loaded

Comment: @LightStyle worked like i charm after i removed the input[type="submit"]

;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is type `"submit"`, however your javascript is looking for type `"button"`.  Try changing to this:

```
function clickButton(val)
{
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) 
    {
       if(buttons[i].type == 'submit' && buttons[i].value == val) 
       {
           buttons[i].click();
           break; //this will exit for loop, but if you want to click every button with the value button then comment this line
       }
    }
}
```

And ensure that you pass the correct value when calling this function:

```
clickButton('continue');
```

Answer (score 0):

Type of your button is "submit" not "button":

```
<input type="submit" value="continue">
```

Change this:

```
buttons[i].type == 'submit'
```